# How much shared memory does Postgresql need per max_locks_per_transaction?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql 10 database with about 300k tables in 23k schemas. I am trying to upgrade to Postgresql 13 using pg_upgradecluster. This is failing while attempting dump all the schemas:

```
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE "a45119740"."activity_hrc" IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

Is setting max_locks_per_transaction to 300k something that can be done? I haven't be able to find anything explaining how much shared memory this might need. The machine has 64G of RAM.

(I understand that I need to change my db design .. I have been backing up one schema at a time until now so wasn't aware of this problem)

Comment: You don't need to set `max_locks_per_transaction` to 300k - [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-locks.html#GUC-MAX-LOCKS-PER-TRANSACTION)  the total number of locks is calculated by `max_locks_per_transaction * max_connections`. So if you have `max_connections` at 200 setting `max_locks_per_transaction` to 1500 would work for 300k tables. But I doubt you need that much. It's probably closer to the number of tables in the biggest database, rather than _all_ of them. But if you go that high you might need to adjust kernel resources as well.

Comment: Tx. All the tables are in one database unfortunately. I am going to try make a plan to avoid having to do the upgrade until I can change the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lock table needs to be big enough to lock all your tables and metadata tables.

Since the lock table has room enough for

```
max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)
```

locks, all you need to do is set `max_locks_per_transaction` big enough that the lock table can hold the locks your `pg_dump` and the other workload needs.

To answer the question how much space each entry in the lock table needs, that can vary based on your architecture, but in general it is `sizeof(LOCK) + sizeof(LOCKTAG)`, which is 168 bytes on my Linux system.